# Why did this question still have a "duplicate error" link?

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions

In [Why don't we pluralize "foot" in measurements?](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/28457/revisions) I noticed there was still the link to the duplicate question, even if the question has been re-opened.

Should not the link be supposed to be removed, once the question is re-open? It doesn't seem to automatically happen.

```
> **Possible Duplicate:**  
> [&ldquo;Forty foot&rdquo; or &ldquo;forty feet&rdquo;?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28433/forty-foot-or-forty-feet)  

<!-- End of automatically inserted text -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been recently fixed: The text about the duplicated question is removed when the question is reopened, without anyone having to manually remove the automatically inserted text.

Answer (score 2):

This does not happen automatically, so edit it out if necessary.